# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app). {Flutter web}

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me89W.jpg)**

FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

- call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

**

For more than 7 days myself trying to solve my "flutter admin web app" problem. But I can't.

√  My firebase auth is: Anonymous
√  Flutter (Channel beta, 2.7.0-3.1.pre
√  Dart version 2.15
√ Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
31.0.0)
√  Chrome - develop for the web
√  Android Studio (version 2020.3)

How can I solve the problem?

**Please help me. Who knows, dear mentor.**

*index.html (file)*

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="grocery_admin_app_flutter">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>grocery_admin_app_flutter</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let useHtml = // ...
    if(useHtml) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    } else {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
    }
  </script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAgoXpOjiZntQBEMqt7ZDrcFpLRmH1ZwCM",
    authDomain: "jaituncshop.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://jaituncshop-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "jaituncshop",
    storageBucket: "jaituncshop.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "338592147861",
    appId: "1:338592147861:web:14315ce1d827ad50c1ee9c",
    measurementId: "G-TG69GZ1VSX"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>



<script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem yesterday and most solutions didn't resolve the problem. I finally solved it and will post my entire index.html so you can use it. If possible, use it verbatim and when it works, you can then start editing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="fiber">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>Your title</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      databaseURL: "...,
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "..."
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But simply looking at your code, I can tell you that this line `<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>` must come last since it makes use of 'app'

Comment: W0W.Thanks, Dear, it's working but firebase auth didn't work, didn't logging.

Comment: For mine, auth worked. What error message is auth giving you?

Comment: No error, but not logging. (Invalid user name).I will share my code or repo wit you mentor.

Comment: [github repo link](https://github.com/arafat1971/jaitunapp_web-master)

Comment: Invalid username. Can you confirm that the username logs in on android? And this should be a problem with your code, not Firebase Auth.

Comment: Let me check out your link.

Comment: [Photo](https://github.com/arafat1971/jaitunapp_web-master/issues/1)

Comment: Please Please help Mentor, I have been 1 year it's my start-up.

Comment: No problem brother. Okay, try this.

Comment: Remove this line `final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();` and the future that waits for _initialization in your login_screen.dart. You only need to initialize a firebase app once in your main.dart

Comment: Print these 3 values and let me know what the are `if (value.exists) {print(value.exists); print(value['username']); print(value['password']);` in your login_screen.dart after their if statements.

Comment: Check your GitHub, I created a pull request. check my suggestions there.

Comment: I want to plant trees for you, to increase the oxygen in the earth. Thanks most valuables thanks

Comment: Lol, so glad I could help, you're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted and if possible upvote it so other users can easily find it.

Comment: what is wrong with this line of code `LoginScreen.id:(context)=>LoginScreen()`?

Comment: Now the happen and problem is: Error: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:6236/dart_sdk.js:5406:11)

Comment: Please make a time for my problem,please help me, Dear Mentor.

Comment: [this problem stack,Dear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788077/error-bad-state-cannot-get-a-field-on-a-documentsnapshotplatform-which-does-no)

Comment: Please help me ):

Comment: **Please help mentor**

Comment: I have posted an answer. Sorry I wasn't notified of your reply on the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and in the end it seems my issue was that I was using a `name` in `initializeApp`:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  name: 'I HAD A NAME HERE',
);
```

On android this works, and later calls to `.instance` succeed etc. However, on web it fails to set up as the default app correctly.

To fix I simply removed the name...and [filed a bug](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9400), so hopefully this gets fixed.

A note regarding many of the other solutions here: according to the research I've done, in the latest versions of firebase for flutter web it should not be required to put any code in `index.html` as of https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/7358, see https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8572