# Error: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

[**Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIfHE.jpg)  How to solve the problem Error: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist ?

dependencies:

√ firebase_core: ^1.3.0
√ cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
√ ars_dialog: ^1.0.8
√ alert_dialog: ^1.0.0
√ firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
√ flutter_admin_scaffold: ^0.0.5
√ firebase: ^9.0.1
√ firebase_storage: ^8.1.3
√ chips_choice: ^2.0.1
√ flutter_switch: ^0.2.1
√ email_validator: ^1.0.6

My GitHub repo https://github.com/arafat1971/jaitunapp_web-master

```
class FirebaseServices {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference banners = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('slider');
  CollectionReference vendors =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors');
  CollectionReference category =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('category');
  CollectionReference boys = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('boys');
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getAdminCredentials(id) {
    var result = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Admin').doc(id).get();
    return result;
  }

  //Banner
  Future<String> uploadBannerImageToDb(url) async {
    String downloadUrl = await storage.ref(url).getDownloadURL();
    if (downloadUrl != null) {
      firestore.collection('slider').add({
        'image': downloadUrl,
      });
    }
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  deleteBannerImageFromDb(id) async {
    firestore.collection('slider').doc(id).delete();
  }

  //vendor

  updateVendorStatus({id, status}) async {
    vendors.doc(id).update({'accVerified': status ? false : true});
  }

  updateTopPickedVendor({id, status}) async {
    vendors.doc(id).update({'isTopPicked': status ? false : true});
  }



  Future<String> uploadCategoryImageToDb(url, catName) async {
    String downloadUrl = await storage.ref(url).getDownloadURL();
    if (downloadUrl != null) {
      category.doc(catName).set({
        'image': downloadUrl,
        'name': catName,
      });
    }
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  Future<void> saveDeliverBoys(email, password) async {
    boys.doc(email).set({
      'accVerified': false,
      'address': '',
      'email': email,
      'imageUrl': '',
      'location': GeoPoint(0, 0),
      'mobile': '',
      'name': '',
      'password': password,
      'uid': ''
    });
  }

  //update delivery boy approved status

  updateBoyStatus({id, context, status}) {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context,
        blur: 2,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF84c225).withOpacity(.3),
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    progressDialog.show();
    // Create a reference to the document the transaction will use
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('boys').doc(id);

    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      // Get the document
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);

      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        throw Exception("User does not exist!");
      }

      // Update the follower count based on the current count
      // Note: this could be done without a transaction
      // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()

      // Perform an update on the document
      transaction.update(documentReference, {'accVerified': status});
    }).then((value) {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
      showMyDialog(
          title: 'Delivery Boy Status',
          message: status == true
              ? "Delivery boy approved status updated as Approved"
              : "Delivery boy approved status updated as Not Approved",
          context: context);
    }).catchError((error) => showMyDialog(
      context: context,
      title: 'Delivery Boy Status',
      message: "Failed to update delivery boy status: $error",
    ));
  }

  Future<void> confirmDeleteDialog({title, message, context, id}) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(message),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Delete'),
              onPressed: () {
                deleteBannerImageFromDb(id);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> showMyDialog({title, message, context}) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(message),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are trying to fetch a `document` from Firestore that does not exist.

Comment: Yes,      Error: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:7706/dart_sdk.js:5406:11)

Comment: [Github repo](https://github.com/arafat1971/jaitunapp_web-master)

Comment: Just above the error message, there is a 'false' printed there. Is that false from `print(value.exists)`? You are trying to fetch a document (maybe the document with id = user) that does not exist

Comment: Post the part of the code that throws that error. if possible, keep adding print statement until you figure out which part of your code breaks, then post that part. Then post screenshot of your Firestore database showing the data you are trying to fetch.

Comment: [Error link Screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/lIVJa54) **Error link say _Internal Server Error_**

Comment: **[Firestore database Screenshot](https://imgur.com/dC2CJI1)** (https://imgur.com/dC2CJI1)

Comment: please help, mentor

Comment: Sorry, I was not notified of your reply. In your first screenshot, I don't think that is the correct link. your link should be like this: `localhost:7706/` (without this part `dart_sdk.js:5406:11`).

Answer (score 1):

Well this usually happens when you want to get or set a field in cloud Firestore that doesn't exist in this case it might be a typo that you made so Cross check or rather click on the error message on the console and send a screenshot of that particular line of code causing that error

Comment: **[Screenshot]** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIfHE.jpg)

Comment: [Error link Screenshot] (https://imgur.com/ogZAOgi) error link say **Internal Server Error**

Comment: **Please help**

Comment: **[This is my GitHub repo please run my project and fixed that,Please](https://github.com/arafat1971/jaitunapp_web-master)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the line of code you use to check if a user is logged in:
`_services.getAdminCredentials(username)`

and getAdminCredentials is defined like this;

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getAdminCredentials(id) {
  var result = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Admin').doc(id).get();
  return result;
}
```

So if you call `_services.getAdminCredentials('Admin')`, you want to get the document with id = 'Admin'. From your Firestore screenshot, your document id is 'qysr...'. So it won't work. Rather, rewrite your code like this:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAdminCredentials(String id) {
  var result = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Admin')
      .where('username', isEqualTo: id)
      .get();
  return result;
}
```

Then call it like this in your login.dart

```
_services.getAdminCredentials(username).then((value) async {
    if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      // document exist
      if (value.docs.first.get('username') == username) {
        // username is correct
        if (value.docs.first.get('username') == password) {
          // password is correct
          // continue the rest of your code.
```

OR better still, you can save your documents using id as username

Comment: `lib/screens/login_screen.dart:34:23: Error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.
            if (value.docs.first.get('username') == password) {`

Comment: Now showing the error

Comment: **Please run my project with your firebase and fix the problem, make end the whole problem Dear Mentor, The problem Pain me, this is my dream Startup, god gives you knowledge of the problem, please help.**

Comment: [This is the project titorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5sbiL655Cs&list=PLLMOQJG4zQsVTtWRbfCPrp_UkfXf3I8uC&index=21)